# Acer Aspire desktop won't boot without a flash disk pluggeg in

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have a very strange problem that I 've never encountered before in my 7 years fixing computers.

The computer with not boot to Windows unless any USB stick is plugged into any usb port. The bizarre thing is that it actually boots to Windows and not to the USB drive. Any USB will do, and none of these have any bootable os, they actually have music and other files.

In BIOS I have the boot sequence set to Internal Hard disk. The only USB setting I see to be relevant is where USB controller is enabled.

Anyone faced with this unusual problem before? Is the PC just totally whacked?

Comment: Boot with a USB stick, then uninstall USB stick from device manager, then shut down. Now boot without USB stick.

Comment: What do you actually get when not booting with a USB stick plugged in? Does it complain that no bootable devices are installed?

Comment: With USB stick plugged in, it does not complain. But it actually boots to Windows not from the stick. It's even funny that the sub stick does not 've any boot files just ordinary files like mp3s.

Comment: As CharlesH asked: what does the computer complain if the USB stick is NOT inserted?